# What does "f (a -> b)" type signature mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm trying to understand applicatives in Haskell. Can't figure out what does following type signature mean:

```
f (a -> b)
```

For example:

```
foo :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a)
foo = Just (+1)
```

How can I understand the meaning of `Maybe (a -> a)`? Is it a function? If it is, which types of arguments are allowed? 
Also obviously I'm new in functional programming, will be grateful for any resources on this topic.

Comment: Do you know what `Maybe a` means? If you know that, and what `a -> a` means, just put them together.

Comment: Well it is a `Just` data constructor that wraps (has as parameter) a *function* with type `Num a => a -> a`. In Haskell functions are "first class citizens". You can use functions as parameters, return functions, etc. Here it thus wraps a function that takes a number as parameter, and returns `1 +` that number.

Comment: Yeah, It's clear for me, I can't just understand how can I use it in this particular example.

Comment: Well `f (a -> b)` is called an Applicative Functor. A function in a context like `Just (+1)`. You may use the applicative operator `<*>` to operate it among the same context values like `Just (+1) <*> Just 2` and the result would be ... `Just 3`.

Comment: for the resources, check out https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can imagine `f (a -> b)` as a function of type `a -> b` wrapped in a context. It is mostly used in the context of `Applicative`s, that `Maybe a` is a prominent example for.

`Applicative`s are an extension of `Functor`s. A typical example for using `Applicative`s are functions with multiple arguments.

What if we have two `Maybe Int`s that we want to add up. We could try by partially applying `+` with `fmap` aka `<$>`. Thus we might try:

```
f :: Maybe (Int -> Int)
f = (+) <$> Just 3
```

But now, how do we apply this to a second argument. That's where we need the `Applicative` typeclass. It defines the `<*>` function. It has the type

```
<*> :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Thus we can use it to apply a second `Maybe Int` to our partially applied function `f` by doing:

```
> f <*> Just 4
Just 7
```

Without the helper function `f` the syntax resembles standard function application:

```
> (+) <$> Just 3 <*> Just 4
Just 7
```

For further reference see the chapter on [applicative functors](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) of learnyouahaskell.

Comment: I think this answer is potentially misleading - while `Maybe` has an `Applicative` instance, that doesn't mean `f (a -> b)` for some arbitrary type constructor `f` is necessarily applicative.

Answer (score 4):

In functional programming, functions are not so different from numbers or any other kind of value.  Really the only difference is that the way you use a function is by applying it to an argument.

A value of type `Maybe a` is either the value `Nothing` or it is `Just x`, where `x` is of type `a`. So if you have a value of type `Maybe (a -> a)`, like your `foo`, it is either `Nothing`, or it is `Just f` where `f` is a function `a -> a`.  In the least fancy way, you would use it like this:

```
case foo of
    Nothing -> "There was no function"
    Just f -> "There was a function, and its value at 0 is " ++ show (f 0)
```

So if it turns out that `foo` is not `Nothing`, then it contains `Just` a function as its value.

---

@Erich is right that especially the literal expression `f (a -> b)` is likely to be related to applicative functors, but that is not necessarily so.  For example, a favorite type of mine is the type of isomorphisms -- equivalences between two types:

```
data Iso a b = Iso (a -> b) (b -> a)
```

`Iso` isn't even a `Functor` (a prerequisite of `Applicative`), but it is still quite useful.  It turns out that pairs are equivalent to functions from `Bool`.  We could construct such an equivalence as an `Iso` value:

```
pairEquiv :: Iso (a,a) (Bool -> a)
pairEquiv = 
    Iso (\(x,y) -> \b -> if b then x else y) -- from pair to function
        (\f -> (f True, f False))            -- from function to pair
```

Here `(Bool -> a)` appears as an argument to a type constructor, and it just means that if you give the `Iso` a pair, it will give you a function back, and vice versa.